# Add digital signature appearance programmatically?

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, cryptography, digital-signature

I am signing my PDF files programmatically and I would like to add the signature appearance to the PDF : what objects would I need to achieve this ? I know I have to `Annotations`, `BBox` and `XObject` but I don't really know in which order and if I need other things. It is really hard to debug this kind of stuff to find the right configuration so any help would be appreciated !

This is the kind of appearance I want to have :

[image]

I am using Zend_Pdf to handle my files.

Comment: Just a small note, in case you forgot: the signature value itself can of not be included as otherwise the signature itself would be dependent on itself. I don't know the answer but I've added some tags in the hope to attract more persons to look at the question. Note however that the question is pretty broad (i.e. it may attract comments such as: "what have you tried") ...